# Checking for event-rsvp status and showing disabled/enabled RSVP-button

Tags: javascript, facebook, events, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm still a bit unsure how I would find this in the documentation, but I'd like to check whether the logged-in user has RSVP'ed to an fb-event or not, and show the "I'm attending" button depending on that... I've already got the login-button hooked up and the proper permissions (user_events and rsvp_event), just not sure how to go about this using the JS SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the [`event_member`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event_member/) FQL table, something like:

```
FB.api(
    {
        method: 'fql.query',
        query: 'select rsvp_status from event_member where eid = "EVENT_ID" and uid=me()'
    }, function(response) {
        alert(response[0].rsvp_status);
    }
);
```

Would return (alert) something like: `declined`

Comment: That didn't work, i get an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rsvp_status' of undefined". Pasted in your exact code except I replaced EVENT_ID with the actual eid for the event...

Comment: Note: this code is deprecated & will not work with the Graph API v2.0 or higher - instead it will produce this error message: `REST API is deprecated for versions v2.1 and higher`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Graph API to do this. There are two scenarios that may be of interest: (1) For an event, you want to list if the user is attending, and (2) for a user, you want to list the event's they're attending. You need the `user_events` permission for both scenarios.

For (1): HTTP GET /EVENT_ID/attending. This will return an array of objects with `{id, name, rsvp_status}` fields. Look for the User ID you're interested in and, if they've RSVP'd, then the `rsvp_status` field will tell you if they're attending.

For (2): HTTP GET /USER_ID/events. This will return all the events for the user with several fields, but also `{id, name, rsvp_status}` fields as above. This time, look for the Event ID you're interested in, and then the `rsvp_status` field will tell you if the current user is attending, not attending, maybe attending, or hasn't RSVP'd (i.e. `rsvp_status` is `unsure`).

Comment: Is it really advised to use the Graph API over FQL in this case? That would mean pulling **ALL** data using the Graph API is more efficient than pulling a single record using FQL!!

Comment: True. It all depends on what you're trying to accomplish. You can be more specific with FQL, but Graph API is easy and consistent if you're dealing with multiple events or multiple users.

Comment: Make sense, but for this specific case *I think* FQL is better (and more efficient) until Facebook introduces some end point to the Graph like: `/EVENT_ID/attending/USER_ID` or even better `/USER_ID/events/EVENT_ID` am I correct? :-)

Comment: I can't speak definitively since I don't know the total scope of what you're trying to do, but your approach sounds reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there's an easier way to do all of this. The problem with the FQL query is that there's a delay of like 15-30 seconds after you submit the RSVP for the status to show up. But this works in the graph API without pagination. Try a GET request in this form:

/[event id]/invited?user=[user_id]&access_token=[access_token]

It'll return a data structure with the rsvp_status if the user has RSVPed at all, including for public events where that user wasn't technically "invited." If the data structure is blank, then they haven't RSVPed at all.