# Facebook event + rsvp attending

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to invite users to a Facebook event using fb.api:

```
FB.api('/345345345345453/attending', 'post', function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
```

I also tried this but no help too:

```
FB.api('/345345345345453/attending&access_token + '/ACCESSTOKEN'', 'post', function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
```

I get a message in my log saying:

```
"(#100) User must be able to RSVP to the event."
```

Can anyone help. Thanks.

Comment: This should work in this specific case. It worked for me as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312964/checking-for-event-rsvp-status-and-showing-disabled-enabled-rsvp-button

Answer (score 1):

If you want to invite users, you should be using `invited` not `attending`. [See the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/#invited). Using `attending` automatically marks them as attending your event.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, actually they will click a join button in my app so yes it's attending rather then inviting actually.

Answer (score 0):

Ok happen that I created a Facebook event that is 'SECRET'.