# Facebook User vs Event (get RSVP status for user on event)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

Is there any better way of checking RSVP status of user (logged in our application) vs. specific Event through Graph API, than calling `/v2.3/{user_id}/events` and going through all events to find the one we're interested into and get the `rsvp_status` field there?

What I've tried, and what didn't work:

- `/v2.3/{user_id}/events/{event_id}`
- `/v2.3/{user_id}/events?event={event_id}`
- `/v2.3/{user_id}/events?event_id={event_id}`
- calling all of them, to find out if user is in any of RSVP groups: `/v2.3/{event_id}/{attending|invited|maybe|declined|noreply}?user={user_id}`

Also FQL is not a solution, if anybody wants to C&P existing FQL answers, because that's deprecated since API `v2.0`

This [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7314532) is also wondering about efficiency on using Graph API, because pulling all user's events and going through them is both time and resource expensive operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the answer, which is quite simple:

`/v2.3/{event_id}/invited?user={user_id}`

Currently this method will

- return nothing, if user is not yet part of event (was never invited and never attended/maybe himself)
- return one object, with user object and his `rsvp_status`

`/invited` (what we've seen from testing) contains both users that were invited to the event, and users that joined the event themselves (so don't get confused by the word `invited`, at least unless facebook changes the API again)